# Android AppBarLayout com tabs

Tags: android, android-layout

Como eu posso fazer as tabs do **App Bar Layout** serem funcionais?

Eu creio que só o componente **TabsLayout** não irá ser suficiente, então tenho quase certeza que irei precisar usar um **ViewPager** para gerir a troca (swipe) entre as Tabs e com isso também vem um **EventListener** (acho que isso é provido pelo ViewPager) para poder ficar observando a ação de troca das tabs.

Então, eu creio que o **ViewPager** seria quase um **Fragment** que ficaria recebendo *vários replaces* de acordo com a *posição da tab*.

Pelo que sei, para poder deixar as tabs todas iguais deve se usar ***gravity fill*** para distribuir elas de forma uniforme...

> Agora, como eu posso implementar o layout de tabs parecido com o do
>   WhatsApp?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @ramaral ele é assim https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggVDd.jpg

Comment: Veja [isto](https://www.journaldev.com/12858/android-tablayout-appbarlayout)

Comment: @ramaral Eu irei dar uma olhada assim que possível e retorno feedback

Comment: @ramaral eu dei uma olhada no link que me passou, ate a inserção das tabs eu consegui, agora fazer o conteudo delas trocar é que não...

Comment: O conteúdo são Fragments geridos por um ViewPager. Veja aqui a [continuação daquele tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/12958/android-tablayout-viewpager).